# Access to element inside other HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function in javascript and I wanna to access an element like that

```
$("#iframe")
```

but the console appear as null, the element exists but is in another document in the same page, the structure is like that

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="iframe">
   #document
   <html>
    <body>
     <div id="content">
     </div>
   </body>
  </html>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The $("#iframe") is called inside an event on $("#content") and appear null, but out of that event I called $("#iframe") and appear the element on console, maybe is because here exists two documents HTML.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the JQuery code you have already?

Comment: Is iframe really a DIV?

Comment: @attila it's a div's id? Not the best convention but legal.

Comment: I ask because the OP mentioned two HTML documents.

Comment: <div id="content"><input type="button" value="TOP" onclick="document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.scrollTo(0,0)"></div>

In the console the js function right, but in debug appear an error

Comment: What exactly is your question? You wish to read the contents of an iFrame?

Comment: The iframe has a scroll, I wanna to put the scroll in the Top when you do click to a button inside the second <html>, in the console this function right, but when the function is called inside the second html appear an error, in the second html the iframe not exists